# Pandas filter to specific rows and then combine 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with create_date and create_time.
Create_date is a date and create_time is a datetime.

For some reason there are some create_times in the future but the create_date still looks accurate.

e.g. create_date: 2019-03-29

create_time: 2035-02-26 18:29:59

I want to filter to just the rows i'm interested in:

```
df.loc[df['create_time'] >= '2019-09-23','create_time']
```

And then I want to combing the 2 columns as below

```
pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['create_time'].dt.time.astype(str))
```

Is there an easy way to do something like this:

```
df.loc[df['create_time'] >= '2019-09-23','create_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['create_time'].dt.time.astype(str))
```

The problem with the statement above is the right hasn't applied the filter

The error I get is for a row that should be excluded from the selection.
I can't apply the query to the whole dataframe as some create_times are NaT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `mask`

```
con1=df['create_time'] >= '2019-09-23'
v1=pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['create_time'].dt.time.astype(str))
df.create_time=df.create_time.mask(con1,v1)
```

Comment: This looks like another way of doing it but I still have the issue that it hasn't filtered to the subset when applying the results